# which of the following is impossible?

Tags: geometry

Let A, B, C, D and E be five points marked, in clockwise order, on the
unit circle in the plane (with centre at origin). Let α and β be real numbers
and set f(P) = αx + βy where P is a point whose coordinates are (x, y).
Assume that f(A) = 10, f(B) = 5, f(C) = 4 and f(D) = 10. Which of the
following are impossible?

(a) f(E) = 2

(b) f(E) = 4

(c) f(E) = 5

I have try this question many times , but from my point of view   the answer  is f(E) = 5 becoz it is moving in clockwise direction and after f(E) =5 then f(E)=10, so my answer is f(E)=5. I don't know   whether answer is correct or not

if anbody help  me , i would be very thankful to him...

Comment: The three options all look wrong to me.

Comment: They are all impossible. Necessarely $f(E)> 10$. Edit: oh, another such topic answers this, already.

Comment: @ sahiba arora   ,,,it is a 2008 . nbhm phd question

Answer (score 1):

They're all impossible.

The points $A,D$ are  on the line  $αx + βy = 10$.

The points $B,C$ are in the open half-plane  $αx + βy < 10$.

Since $A,B,C,D,E$ are ordered counterclockwise, it follows that $E$ is in the open half-plane $αx + βy > 10$.

Comment: i m not getting the line      point B , C are in the open half plane ax + by less than 10 @ quasi

Comment: It's given that $fB)=5$ and $f(C)=4$, which means
$$αx_B + βy_B = 5\;\;\text{and}\;\;αx_C + βy_C =4$$
so the points $B,C$ are in the region
$$αx + βy <10$$
which is an open half-plane.

Comment: that mean ax+by = 9 less than 10 ,,am i  right@ quasi

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But note, all the lines with equations of the form $αx + βy =k$ where $k$ is a fixed real number are parallel to each other. Any particular one of those lines splits the plane into two half-planes. Thus, the line $αx + βy = 10$ splits the plane into the two open half-planes $αx+ βy<10$ and $αx+ βy>10$.

Comment: ok  i was  think  that  f(B) + f (c)= 4+5 =9, less than 10,,,,,,,but   now    i got it  @quasi